# Jasmine test private callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I know that calling private functions directly in unitTests is not a good practice and we must test the private code trough public methods.

I'm in a case that I don't know what to do to achieve what I want. I want to know if a callback function has been called from my interval. This is implemented in an angular controller.

```
function prepareInterval() {
  self.callbacksData = [];
  if(self.DynamicValuesList !== null) {
    self.myPromise = $interval(callbackFunction, userInputInterval * 1000);
  }
}
```

and my callback function only shows the data from the callbackFunction. I want to unitTest if that callbackFunction has been called but I can't.

I tried https://makandracards.com/makandra/32477-testing-settimeout-and-setinterval-with-jasmine

```
it('myUnitTest', function(){
  //Prepare data
  var controller = createController();

  spyOn(controller, 'callbackFunction');
  expect(controller.callbackFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The error that I'm getting is.

> callbackFunction() method does not exist

EDIT: By the way I'm injecting the angular mock in the beforeEach function

Comment: So it is the callbackFunction that is private?

Comment: @Randy exactly. That callbackFunction is not defined inside my self object as result is not exposed publicly. I want to check if that private function has been called.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a slightly different approach here.

Obviously you don't want the `callbackFunction` itself to be exposed, so don't. Keep it private.

You do, however, return it as a value to your `self` instance.

```
    self.myPromise = $interval(callbackFunction, userInputInterval * 1000);
```

So what you cán test, is that `self.myPromise` value. If that value is containing the interval, your interval has been set and thus you can be pretty sure your method has been called.

I expect that `self` object to be the controller, so you can just test the value of `self.myPromise` like this:

```
it('myUnitTest', function(){
  //Prepare data
  var controller = createController();

  expect(controller.myPromise).toBe( /* undefined? */);
});
```

---

**update**

Just to test the interval value > 0:

You can try to refactor for testability. I'm not sure if the stringmatcher works on numbers though, and don't have time for a test myself now :)

```
function prepareInterval() {
  self.callbacksData = [];
  if(self.DynamicValuesList !== null) {
    self.myPromise = $interval;
    self.myPromise(callbackFunction, userInputInterval * 1000);
  }
}

it('myUnitTest', function(){
  //Prepare data
  var controller = createController();

  spyOn(controller, 'myPromise');
  expect(controller.myPromise).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function), jasmine.stringMatching(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/));
});
```

Comment: Ok your answer is what I was applying in other cases and it's correct. Maybe I must change my question because if you check my interval depends on an user input parameter. I want to check that i.e. that userInputInterval is minor than 0 or null I still calling my interval every 1000 ms. Is that the reason what I want to check if my callback function has been called after that I increment the tickets as seen in the link that I attached

Comment: Just as a sidenote then, if `userInputInterval` is < 1, it would never call your method every second this way. If you want a minimum of one second, try this: `userInputInterval && userInputInterval > 1 ? userInputInterval * 1000 : 1000`

Comment: I'm doing that in other part of the code when I receive my userinput parameters. I want to create a unit Test to check that. I'm thinking that maybe what I must do is test only that when an userinput period is less than 0 or null my interval timer is still checked to 1000. I don't know if that info is stored in the returned promise

Comment: @acostela You could try this update but I'm not sure if it suits your needs :| Good luck for now anyways!